# wamp changing port number

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I use WAMP and if I go `http://localhost:8080/` its working nice, If I go `http://localhost:8080/source` its working nice, If I go `http://localhost:8080/source/auth_sample` its working nice, BUT if I going `http://localhost:8080/poweram/` then its not going there, this going `http://localhost/poweram/` , but why ? I need to go `localhost:8080` not to `localhost`, Anybody can help me ??

poweram is Wordpress site..

Comment: I think it'll be that in your wordpress settings it is redirecting to the site name or similar setting -- you need to edit that to include the port number. related answer: http://superuser.com/questions/371900/8080-port-in-nginx-not-able-to-serve-for-certain-wordpress-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into your database and navigate to the '_options' table. There you need to change records like 'siteurl' and 'home'. Be sure the correct port number (8080) is included in the settings records.

Comment: I changed siteurl and home to http://localhost:8080/poweram but still not working

Comment: Is it still redirecting to port 80?

Comment: Hmm, can you access wp-admin or is that also redirecting?

Comment: If I trying to go there , then I got `Error establishing a database connection

This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database server at localhost. This could mean your host's database server is down.`

Comment: I can go  localhost:8080/poweram/wp-admin , but no  localhost:8080/poweram  ??

Comment: Can you go to Settings->Permalinks, click save and try again? This will reset the rewrite rules and create a new .htaccess file.